# Progress Bar gem or plugin for Rails 3 that uses jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, progress-bar

Does anyone know of a progress bar gem, plugin, or tutorial that will asynchronously allow updating a progress bar from a controller? I do not want to use prototype or JRails. The  part of the DOM that I want to refresh is not in a form. I need to be able to refresh the progress bar as the Rails control performs several tasks called within a loop. I want to refresh the progress bar after each task is executed in the loop. I know how to create the progress bar in the specific  tag in document. I just do not know what event to use or how to repeatedly call that event so the progress bar refreshes the progress indication.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. http://blog.bitcrowd.net/uploadify-paperclip-rails-3-and-sessions/

There is no one solution for it. But a lot of older solutions will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this gem is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/yrgoldteeth/css3-progress-bar-rails